# Why would a "No SLF4J" provider found error occur when SLF4J is in Maven pom.xml file?

Tags: java, maven, log4j, pom.xml, slf4j

I am currently getting the below errors when trying to run a Spring Java program.

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.11/logback-classic-1.2.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.19.0/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.19.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
```

Here is the section in the pom.xml file that has the SLF4J and Log4J dependencies.  This same section has worked in previous projects.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I don't have any components that are targeting  indings for slf4j-api version 1..x or earlier.  This error message seems to both say that I don't have SLF4J and that I have the wrong version.

If there are any thoughts on how to resolve this, I would appreciate it.  Thank you!

I have tried using different dependencies in the pom.xml file, but ultimately these have worked in a previous program.  I have also tried looking at dependencies that might also use SLF4J and excluding SLF4J from them, but I am still getting an error message.  I have tried solutions from other similar questions asked but keep getting the same error.

Comment: You have log4j and logback in the classpath remove one.

Comment: @Jens Would you happen to know how to remove it?  Thanks!

Comment: it must be a dependency in your project. remove it from there

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on [this documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/):

> Due to a break in compatibility in the SLF4J binding, as of release 2.19.0 two SLF4J to Log4j Adapters are provided.
>
> 1. `log4j-slf4j-impl` should be used with SLF4J 1.7.x releases or older.
> 2. `log4j-slf4j2-impl` should be used with SLF4J 2.0.x releases or newer.
>
> Applications that take advantage of the Java Module System should use SLF4J 2.0.x and log4j-slf4j2-impl.

So the simplest way (if you need SLF4J 2) is to use `<artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>`. The other thing you can do is to revert back to `slf4j-api` 1.7.x.

**Other notes:**

- The SLF4J log shows that `logback-classic` is also present in the dependency tree. You need to select either `logback-classic` or the log4j binding. Run `mvn dependency:tree` on your project to find where `logback-classic` is being added.
- If you want to keep `logback-classic`, then same as mentioned above, you need to use the `logback-classic` compatible with SLF4J 2.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Gradle. Adding this dependency worked

```
implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j2-impl:2.20.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.36</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I downgrade the slf4j version from 1.8.* to 1.7.36 ,and It works, otherwise it happens:
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.